# Extract list to multiple distinct list

Tags: scala, list

How can I extract Scala list to List with multiple distinct list in Scala?

From

```
val l = List(1,2,6,3,5,4,4,3,4,1)
```

to

```
List(List(1,2,3,4,5,6),List(1,3,4),List(4))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a (rather inefficient) way to do this: group by value, sort result by size of group, then use first group as a basis for per-index scan of the original groups to build the distinct lists:

```
scala> val l = List(1,2,6,3,5,4,4,3,4,1)
l: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 6, 3, 5, 4, 4, 3, 4, 1)

scala> val groups = l.groupBy(identity).values.toList.sortBy(- _.size)
groups: List[List[Int]] = List(List(4, 4, 4), List(1, 1), List(3, 3), List(5), List(6), List(2))

scala> groups.head.zipWithIndex.map { case (_, i) => groups.flatMap(_.drop(i).headOption) }
res9: List[List[Int]] = List(List(4, 1, 3, 5, 6, 2), List(4, 1, 3), List(4))
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative approach after grouping like in the first answer by @TzachZohar is to keep taking one element from each list until all lists are empty:

```
val groups = l.groupBy(identity).values

Iterator
  // continue removing the first element from every sublist, and discard empty tails
  .iterate(groups)(_ collect { case _ :: (rest @ (_ :: _)) => rest } )
  // stop when all sublists become empty and are removed
  .takeWhile(_.nonEmpty)
  // build and sort result lists 
  .map(_.map(_.head).toList.sorted)
  .toList
```

Answer (score 0):

And here's another option - scanning the input N times with N being the largest amount of repetitions of a single value:

```
// this function splits input list into two: 
// all duplicate values, and the longest list of unique values
def collectDistinct[A](l: List[A]): (List[A], List[A]) = l.foldLeft((List[A](), List[A]())) {
  case ((remaining, distinct), candidate) if distinct.contains(candidate) => (candidate :: remaining, distinct)
  case ((remaining, distinct), candidate) => (remaining, candidate :: distinct)
}

// this recursive function takes a list of "remaining" values,
// and a list of distinct groups, and adds distinct groups to the list
// until "remaining" is empty
@tailrec
def distinctGroups[A](remaining: List[A], groups: List[List[A]]): List[List[A]] = remaining match {
  case Nil => groups
  case _ => collectDistinct(remaining) match {
    case (next, group) => distinctGroups(next, group :: groups)
  }
}

// all second function with our input and an empty list of groups to begin with:
val result = distinctGroups(l, List())
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider this approach:

```
trait Proc {
  def process(v:Int): Proc
}
case object Empty extends Proc {
  override def process(v:Int) = Processor(v, Map(0 -> List(v)), 0)
}
case class Processor(prev:Int, map:Map[Int, List[Int]], lastTarget:Int) extends Proc {
  override def process(v:Int) = {
    val target = if (prev==v) lastTarget+1 else 0
    Processor(v, map + (target -> (v::map.getOrElse(target, Nil))), target)
  }
}

list.sorted.foldLeft[Proc](Empty) {
  case (acc, item) => acc.process(item)
}
```

Here we have simple state machine. We iterate over sorted list with initial state 'Empty'. Once 'Empty' processes item, it produces next state 'Processor'.
Processor has previous value in 'prev' and accumulated map of already grouped items. It also has lastTarget - the index of list where last write occured.
The only thing 'Processor' does is calculating the target for current processing item: if it is the same as previous, it takes next index, otherwise it starts from the beginning with index 0.